# Authenticate user via Kentico API PHP

Tags: php, api, authentication, kentico

I have the requirement to permit access to a Wordpress Blog based on a username and password that is stored within a user database which runs on the Kentico CMS (v6.0.21)

I understand how I can override the Wordpress Membership system but am unsure as to how I can access the Kentico API from an external source (preferably if a php example was available, but anything will do).

Does anyone have any examples of how this would be achieved?
What needs to be done on the Kentico side of things to allow access to the API?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Have you already tried to add the references to Kentico DLLs as described [here](http://devnet.kentico.com/docs/devguide/using_api_and_cms_controls_outside_cms_project.htm)?

Comment: No, I am just in the planning/figuring out what I am doing phase at the moment!

Comment: Hi there, I'm in a similar situation where a 3rd party app needs to authenticate users against Kentico userbase. Did you resolve this? I am considering developing an authentication server based on DotNetOpenAuth.dll, any insights or tips? Thanks!